# Why are two functions over-riding each other?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, uploads

I have function in my plugin that is:

```
add_filter('comment_text', 'commentimage_comment_text');
function commentimage_comment_text($comment = '') { 
  $options = get_option('commentimage');
  $id = get_comment_ID();

  $images = $options['images'];
  if (!isset($images) || !is_numeric($images)) $images = 1;
    $url = get_option('siteurl');
    for ($i=0; $i<$images; $i++) {
      if (file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/comment-image/' . $id . ($i==0?'':('-'.$i)) . '-tn.jpg')) {
         $comment .= '<p><a href="' . $url . '/wp-content/comment-image/' . commentimage_find_original($id, $i) . '"><img src="' . $url . '/wp-content/comment-image/' .    $id . ($i==0?'':('-'.$i)) . '-tn.jpg"/></a></p>';
      }
    }
  return $comment;
}
```

Now it is showing a successful image uploaded by my viewers. I want my viewers to have the option of rating them, so for that I write in my plugin just below the above line the following code:

```
 add_filter('comment_text', 'commentimage_comment_text2');
 function commentimage_comment_text2()
 {
   $rtt= "<br>Rating";
   return $rtt;
 }
```

Then my pictures are gone and it shows text rating - I will change the text rating to my desired needs once I get the answer on how to overcome over writing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting the comment text with your `commentimage_comment_text2` filter, try this to append the ratings text:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'commentimage_comment_text2' );
function commentimage_comment_text2( $comment ){
    $rtt = "<br>Rating";

    return $comment.$rtt;
}
```

ps: you forgot the `$comment` input parameter.

Here is a poor man's skematic picture of the filter flow in WordPress ;-)

[image: poor man's skematic image of the filter flow in WordPress]

The filter icon was taken from [here](http://www.veryicon.com/icons/system/crystal-clear-actions/filter.html).

In your case the filter's name is `comment_text` and your two callbacks are `commentimage_comment_text` and `commentimage_comment_text2` with priority `10` (the default).

You can view all the callbacks for this filter with this code snippet:

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
        global $wp_filter;
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $wp_filter['comment_text'],true));
});
```

On my install I get the following output (in my theme's footer part)
of all these callbacks with the corresponding assigned pirorities.

I added your two callbacks `commentimage_comment_text` and `commentimage_comment_text2` so you can see them too:

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
        (
            [make_clickable] => Array
                (
                    [function] => make_clickable
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [wptexturize] => Array
                (
                    [function] => wptexturize
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
            [convert_chars] => Array
                (
                    [function] => convert_chars
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
            [commentimage_comment_text] => Array
                (
                    [function] => commentimage_comment_text
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
            [commentimage_comment_text2] => Array
                (
                    [function] => commentimage_comment_text2
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
    [20] => Array
        (
            [convert_smilies] => Array
                (
                    [function] => convert_smilies
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
    [25] => Array
        (
            [force_balance_tags] => Array
                (
                    [function] => force_balance_tags
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
    [30] => Array
        (
            [wpautop] => Array
                (
                    [function] => wpautop
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
    [31] => Array
        (
            [capital_P_dangit] => Array
                (
                    [function] => capital_P_dangit
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: +1, but could you flesh out an explanation for *why* one callback is overwriting the other (i.e. a bit of explanation for how the filter callback works)?

Comment: thanks, I tried to draw a picture but I'm not sure if it helps :-)

Comment: Wish I could give another +1. :)

Comment: Great and detailed explaination just wow ! .... Sir can I ask you another question its real important ?

Comment: thanks, sure if it's related to the above question, otherwise it might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: +1 Should be [uploaded and added to Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Special:Upload). But license is missing.

Comment: thanks @kaiser, I'm a fan of the Beer-ware-licence, but this should be as open licence as possible ;-) I dont' have access to Codex upload tools, if you think it's worthy for that ;-)

Comment: What? You don't have access? Why do I have access then? I'm slightly confused ... btw, uploader not working currently.

Comment: I only got the "forum" / "plugin author" access

Comment: Why's that? Thought everybody can edit codex...

Comment: ahh sorry, I can log in, I was logged into other parts of wp.org but that was not translated to this page, maybe some different cookies there ;-) But I haven't made any changes to Codex before;-)

Comment: I uploaded it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:schematic-filter-flow.png)