# What does (10, 2) mean when used with add_filter

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

Please tell my what is 10, 2 in below mention code:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_active_class', 10, 2 );

function add_active_class($classes, $item) {

if($item->menu_item_parent == 0 && in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {

    $classes[] = "active";

}

return $classes;

}
```

Comment: Some time ago, I tried to draw a schematic image of this, I don't know if it's helpful to you, but you can check it out [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101689/why-are-two-functions-over-riding-each-other/101695#101695)

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the codex page for [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

The 10 is the `$priority` parameter (10 is default) which defines when your function will run in regards to the other functions which are attached to the `nav_menu_css_class` filter. 2 is the `$accepted_args` parameter which tells wordpress how many parameters the function you want to add will take. In this case your `add_active_class` function can take 2 parameters (`$classes` and `$item`).